# How does Stack Exchange lose my login?

Tags: bug, login, logout

I'm logged in, click a link to a different stack exchange link, and suddenly - I'm not logged in anymore? How does Stack Exchange lose my login information?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you mean by "a different stack exchange link"? Do you mean a link to a different Stack Exchange site? Is it to a site where you have a user or one where you do not? Examples would help.

Comment: @Oded I have this issue as well. It happens when I click on a link to another Stack Exchange site that I have an account for. Sometimes I get the "You have been logged in. Click to refresh" while other times I do not.

Comment: @Cfinley - do you mean that when you don't get the banner, are you logged in already - or do you mean you are expecting the banner and are not logged in?

Comment: @Oded Yes, I don't get the banner when I am not logged in and am expecting it.

Comment: @Cfinley and John, what browser(s) are we talking here?

Comment: @AnnaLear I use Firefox.

Comment: I sometimes get this issue too. When i click login, it automatically logs in from that page though, then redirects me back to where i was.

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but did you clear your cookies prior to clicking this link?

Comment: @DarylGill cookies are not relevant, the login details are stored in the browser's localStorage.

Comment: Then have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: I get this a lot, over more than one browser.  One of the browsers is Chrome.  In spite of the comment above, it smells like it's cookie related to me.  If I erase my cookies, the cycle starts all over again.

Comment: Same issue happens to me both in Chrome & Firefox. Clearing the cookies work as expected.

Comment: I'm working on a replacement for our current global auth workflow. That should resolve this issue.

Comment: I frequently lost my login a few months ago (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267977/temporarily-lost-login-while-being-active), but it hasn't happened much anymore recently.

Comment: @AnnaLear has this gone live? I'm finding for the last couple of weeks that this happens frequently to me (at least once a day) on safari Ipad.

Comment: Only happens in StackOverflow for me (Safari).

Comment: It's happening to me at least once or twice a day on SO, SO meta and SU. (I have those 3 sites always open in pinned tabs in FF on 64-bit Win7.) It seems to be a recent thing, and it's getting pretty annoying.