# Why do I keep getting logged out of Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, bug, login, logout, authentication

I keep on getting logged out of Stack Overflow on my personal computer. This can happen even when I've been logged in earlier in the same day. It used to be that I'd never get logged out of SO (which was how I preferred it!). I've tried both Google and AOL (shudder) as authentication methods, but it doesn't matter (and I don't think it should, right?).

I'm running OS X 10.9.5 and Safari 7.1. I've tried looking at the cookies, but I don't really know what I'm looking at (everything is set to expire in months or years). This doesn't happen on my work computer (same OS and browser versions).

Anything I can do to prevent this from happening? More data points to collect to help diagnose the issue?

Comment: First thing I would check is your IP address. If it's changing rapidly (e.g. every minute) that's the problem.

Comment: Happens to me on iOS too, an average of three times a day.

Comment: There have been numerous threads about this on MSO. Here was my original report: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267977/temporarily-lost-login-while-being-active. Another one: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262223/constantly-being-kinda-logged-off. Recent report on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243734/how-does-stack-exchange-lose-my-login#comment796794_243734. I haven't seen it myself in quite a while.

Comment: @Reto Koradi - thanks, looks like I'm not the only one having this issue. Hopefully this gets fixed soon!

Comment: Update, Jan 19: still happening :(

Comment: ...yeah, still not fixed :(

Comment: After almost 3 years of no problems of this sort, over the last few days this is happening every few minutes to me on Stack Overflow too (but not other SE sites - also my Google login used for auth is stable, as are other sites I use). I cannot see what I am doing differently, and it is *really* annoying . . . In my case Mac OS X 10.10.4 and Chrome browser.

Comment: Wish I could do something about this to get more attention -- on multiple computers, I'm having to log in multiple times per week to each of several different stackexchange sites. If anything, it's gotten worse since last year.

Comment: This is still an issue for me.

Comment: 7-18-2017 Just started happening to me on SO in the last 3 weeks. Was never this bad before. Seems it initially logs me out after the first 30 seconds of being logged in. I could be in the middle of posting an answer or anything. Then it happens after 2 minute intervals if I don't click a link or refresh the page.

Comment: Yep, this is happening to me too now.

Comment: This is still an issue ... I rotate across several laptops/desktops and constantly need to relogin - WHY ?   certainly should be a stackexchange setting to permit extended login period - please don't treat us like idiots

Comment: this is still an issue across any stackexchange site - when people use different computer it logs us out ... please put in a fix ... stop treating us like children who mistakenly leave themselves logged into accounts on public computers ... stackexchange folks are on their own computers ... please fix

Comment: @Noah, Fixed? I hope so... If it's not and you really need help for this tell me

Comment: glad you asked this.  bloody annoying.  pity it hasn't been answered

Comment: I bet they don't store your access tokens in a DB, but rather when the cache evicts it you get thrown out. Otherwise, what explaination would there be. Keep getting logged out every other day.

Comment: I opened chrome dev tools and it had two warnings about "samesite cookies", perhaps that could be it on newer versions of chrome on mac

Comment: almost 8 years, without an answer... i don't really care too much about the problem (it's just annoyng, it doesn't have any other effect than that) but the absense of an answer is just... strange

Comment: Started happening to me a couple weeks ago. I get logged out multiple times a day, not sure why.

Comment: This is happening to me too now.

Comment: Does 1 have idea/solution to this? This is very annoying. Been logged out so frequently now.

Comment: Happens now and then. once a month. sucks

Comment: I use NoScript and Firefox. This issue happens to me if I forget to allow all scripts on the tab I use for StackOverflow.